Adding the same function inside a function
So I basically want to do this:
label.addEventListener('dragend', function(event){
    id++
    var newItem = document.createElement("input" + id)
    newItem.addEventListener('dragend', THISFUNCTION)
    document.getElementById("list").appendChild(newItem)
})


The idea is that when you stop dragging an item another appears and it has the save event and so on. How to do this?


you can refer to the current function if you give it a name and use that name. 2. In this case that's not what you want to do, you'd want to use event delegation thus you wouldn't need to manually add event handlers, only define the event listener once for all current and future elements.

